# A Bayesian network with 4 nodes question

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem, data-analysis, bayesian-network

[image]

Hello. I need to find the following probabilities:

$ \qquad a. P(\neg A, B, \neg C, D) \\
\qquad b. P(A|B,C,D) $

This is my solution:
[image]

I would like to get an opinion on my solution.

Comment: In the independence statement (1), what is meant by A (notA) and B independent? It seems to me that independence of A and B always implies independence of (not A) and B. Also in statement (2) does it only mean C and D independent given *both* A and B? or on the other hand are C and D independent given A, and also independent given B?

Comment: @coffeemath In the statement (1) I meant that A and B are independent because of Bayesian network properties. Therefore, $ A^c $ and B are independent and that's what is needed in the transition above. 
In statement (2) I am actually not so sure. I know that if we have hard evidence on A so C and D are independent given that value. I don't know how given the fact that B's value is given is affecting the independence.

Comment: One other thing: When you write e.g. P(not-A,B,not-C,D) are the commas being used as and [conjunction of all four] so it's the prob. that A false and B true and C false and D true?

Comment: Maor Cohen: I am still wondering about the commas between events, as for example $P(E,F,G)$ --- Does this mean same as $P(E \land F \land G)$?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes the commas are used as conjunction of all events. And the $ \neg $ notation is used as the complement of the event ($ A^c$).

Comment: @coffeemath see my edited post.

Comment: Looks good to me, and also to Daniel S in his answer, which shows more familiarity with Baysean networks than I have.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer looks correct to me.  The Bayesian network encodes some independence relationships between events.  In particular, your network encodes the fact that $A$ and $B$ are independent, but may be dependent given $D$.  This is the so-called "collider" pattern.  $A$ and $B$ are marginally independent.  The relationship between $A$, $C$ and $D$ is of a fork.  $C$ and $D$ are conditionally independent, given $A$.

In your answer, you use the above facts to write

$P(A,B,C,D)=P(C,D|A,B)P(A)P(B)=P(C|A,B)P(D|A,B)P(A)P(B)$

the first equality follows from the marginal independence between $A$ and $B$ and the second from the conditional indepedence between $C$ and $D$.

Finally,

$P(A,B,C,D)=P(C|A)P(A,B)P(D|A,B)=P(C|A)P(A)P(B)P(D|A,B)$

This is the typical result, that the joint distribution is the product of the conditional distributions of events given their parents.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network

Comment: Much appreciated Daniel :)